# Simplfying Expression : Z3 SMT Solver

Tags: z3, simplify, smt

Executing the following query with the Z3 solver:

```
    (declare-const c0 Int)
    (declare-const c1 Int)
    (declare-const c2 Int)

    (assert (exists ((c0_s Int) (c1_s Int) (c2_s Int))
      (and 
        (= (+ c0 c1 c2) 5) (>= c0 0) (>= c1 1) (>= c2 1)
        (= c0_s c0) (= c1_s (- c1 1)) (= c2_s (+ c2 1))
        (= c2_s 3) (= (+ c0_s c1_s) 2)    
      ))
    )

    (apply (then qe ctx-solver-simplify propagate-ineqs))
```

produces the following output:

```
    (goals
     (goal
       (>= c0 0)
       (<= c0 2)
       (>= c1 1)
       (<= c1 3)
       (<= (+ (* (- 1) c0) (* (- 1) c1)) (- 3))
       (<= (+ c1 c0) 3)
       (= c2 2)
       :precision precise :depth 3)
    )
```

where I was expecting a result from the Z3 solver like this:

```
    (goals
     (goal
       (>= c0 0)
       (<= c0 2)
       (>= c1 1)
       (<= c1 3)
       (= (+ c1 c0) 3)
       (= c2 2)
       :precision precise :depth 3)
    )
```

Can anyone explain why Z3 is producing such a complex result instead of what I expected? Is there a way to get Z3 to simplify this output?

Comment: Apparently, Z3 does not know to simplify away the negations. Maybe you should post a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I will request for it as soon as possible if that is the case. However, I was wondering why in the first place it was generating negation when there is no need for it.

Answer (score 3):

You may get a more detailed answer from a member of the core Z3 team, but from my experience working with Z3's integer solver at a low level, I can give a bit of intuition as to why this is happening.

Briefly, in order to solve integer equations, Z3's integer theory solver expects all of its constraints to appear in a very particular and restricted form. Expressions that do not follow this form must be rewritten before they are presented to the solver. Normally this happens internally by a theory rewriter, and any expression can be used in the input constraint set without issue.

The restrictions that apply here (that I am aware of), which help explain why you are seeing this strange-looking output, are as follows:

- The integer solver can represent an equality constraint `(= a b)` as two separate inequality constraints `(<= a b)` and `(>= a b)`. This is why you're seeing two separate constraints over your variables in the model instead of just one equality.
- The integer solver rewrites subtractions, or negated terms, as multiplication by -1. This is why you are seeing these negations in your first constraint, and why the operator is addition instead of subtraction.
- Arithmetic expressions are rewritten so that the second argument to a comparison operator is always a constant value.

In short, what you're seeing is likely an artifact of how the arithmetic theory solver represents constraints internally.

Since the output of your instance is a goal and not a model or proof, these expressions may not have been fully simplified yet, as I believe that intermediate goals are not always simplified (but I don't have experience with this part of the solver).